# Should I index a column which can have only 0 or 1 as value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table in which there is a column named enable which can only store 0 or 1. 
I want to ask should I apply indexing on this column or not.
If yes, How will it improve performance?

**PS** There is a lot of rows in the table and the proportion of 0 and 1 is almost equal.
The number of rows with value 0 = The number of rows with value 1

Comment: You will not receive an unequivocal answer to such a query. If the column is ENUM type, it probably won't change anything about performance. It's best to check the query execution time for a table with and without an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

In general, indexing a binary column is not useful.  There is one exception, where you have few values for what you care about (say `enable = 1`) and lots of queries with that condition.  In that case, a *clustered* index on `enable` can be helpful.  Do note that such an index affects the performance of queries where the value changes (because the row actually needs to move).

A boolean value can also be very effectively used in a multi-column index, clustered or not.